# Определение числа, полученного с помощью Javascript

Tags: html, javascript

Есть исходный код страницы: http://jsfiddle.net/fzrb0peg/29/

Работаем со средним баллом)

Как можно задать следующий скрипт: Если полученное число - целое, то прибавить к нему два ноля (Пример: было 3, стало 3.00); Если полученное число - *(сколько-то)* целых *(сколько-то)* десятых, то прибавить к нему один ноль (Пример: было 3.4, стало 3.40). Как сделать правильность их написания, чтобы Javascript округлял их до сотых, и чтобы ноли тоже отображались?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе уже подсказали. Так пробовал

```
alert((3.5).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: Как сделать правильность их написания, чтобы Javascript округлял их до сотых]

Comment: Это не то вообще-то. Я спрашивал не про это.

Comment: У меня и так этот скрипт написан на jsfiddle. Если я уже округлил, и у меня результат получился 3.5, то как заставить написать его как 3.50. Вот в чём вопрос.

Comment: Если бы я решил этот вопрос, я бы не пошёл сразу на этот сайт, а для начала, конечно же, поискал в гугле.

Comment: @Никита___, там второй ссылкой ответ (не первой).

Comment: @Никита___, запрос «How to ...» лучший друг программиста. И ещё, запретите себе копипаст, как только рука тянется скопировать строчку кода, задайте себе вопрос «а не ерунду ли я делаю», это очень помогает. Вот ваша задача без пасты: http://jsfiddle.net/doezuwoe/

Comment: @Никита___, и ещё, подтяните  алгебру и геометрию ;]